# How to display blocks of text in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I'm trying to build a module that lets users with a certain role post messages that will be displayed for users with a different role. I'd like this to simply be one module that handles both these things, however, the furthest I've gotten is setting up the form to post messages.

I'd like to show the posted messages on the same page as the input form (and hide the form for the unauthorised users), but I just can't figure out what I have to do to show the messages. How hard can it be to display some simple text?

So far I've added an item to the menu that links to the page with a form on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the boxes module to have online editing of this text that other users will see. If you're set on Using your custom Form you could put your text in a block.

Answer (score 0):

The [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module will let you restrict view permission for a given content type to users having a certain role.

For setting up the layout, you might want to put the posted messages in a block or use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).